# is it possible to change margin sizes if a page contains a margin note or side note?

Tags: margins, sidenotes

I am working on a textbook.  I like the aesthetics of side notes when they are present on a page.  I do not like the aesthetics of the large empty margin when no side note is present on a page.  Is there a way for latex to dynamically modify the margin size if no side note is detected on a page (or vice versa).

I've explored using afterpage along with newgeometry, but they require specific knowledge about where the pagebreaks will occur.

Comment: The `changepage` package defines the  `adjustmargins` environment which doesn't require a page break.

Comment: Have you considered the `tufte-book` class? If not, run `texdoc tufte`. It is  designed to have side table, figures or whatever in a huge side margin, but allow also `fullwidth` environments and full widths floats even in the same page.